# Is it normal/legal in Germany for employer to withhold salary until work equipment is returned?

Tags: salary, germany, equipment

My contract ended 30th November and I didn't receive my November Salary. My boss says that my salary will only be released  after my work laptop and phone are released. The combined cost is about 450 euros. This stipulation for paying my last salary was not made aware to me until today.

Is withholding salary like this normal/legal in Germany? Also, how are my health insurance and unemployment benefits affected? I expect to start receiving the latter at the end of this month.

Comment: "Is withholding salary like this normal/legal in Germany" almost certainly not, but we have around here experts in german employment law that will be able to give a more detailed answer than I could. I imagine they could deduct value of the hardware if you didn't return it timely. Though that begs the question, why didn't you return the kit?

Comment: Because we only arranged the return today. My ex-boss never said I had to return the hardware before a specific time.

Comment: @Duzii2 - Is there a reason you wait to be asked for the hardware, provided by the company, to acomplish a job you knew you were no longer going to do?

Comment: Why don't you just return the stuff and get paid? What's the problem  you are trying to solve? Picking a legal argument is probably the worst possible way to proceed (regardless of who is right or wrong).

Comment: _"My ex-boss never said I had to return the hardware before a specific time."_ The "normal" expectation is to hand things in on the last day of work. Now, if you're 100% remote, there may be some more leeway in that, but you (and your boss) should have arranged this *before* your last day.

Comment: I am 100% remote.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is legal.

I don't know whether it is *normal*, but since you seem to have some problems with your employer and apparently did not arrange the return of your equipment in time, it seems the employer's distrust is not entirely unfounded.

This is not specialized labor law, it's basic civil law (§ 273 Abs. 1 BGB) really:

> (1) Hat der Schuldner aus demselben rechtlichen Verhältnis, auf dem seine Verpflichtung beruht, einen fälligen Anspruch gegen den Gläubiger, so kann er, sofern nicht aus dem Schuldverhältnis sich ein anderes ergibt, die geschuldete Leistung verweigern, bis die ihm gebührende Leistung bewirkt wird (Zurückbehaltungsrecht).

Translated:

> (1) If the debtor has a due claim against the obligee from the same legal relationship on which his obligation is based, he may, unless the obligation arises otherwise, refuse to perform the service owed until the service due to him is provided (right of retention).

Which means, if you still have their equipment, which constitutes a "due claim" from "the same legal relationship" as your salary, they may keep your payments until you returned it. As always in German law, it has to be proportional. So they cannot keep your last 3 monthly salarys because you still have the used and broken office stapler. But computer equipment will probably be worth a few hundred € at least, so I would say delaying your last pay check, being the smallest possible unit they could influence, until it is returned is indeed reasonable.

As a side note, you don't have to pay for shipping the equipment. Shipping is the employers problem. All you have to do is make sure it is available to be picked up from your doorstep by a courier of their choosing. However, normally, for people not taking an adversarial approach to this, you will ship it and get reimbursed for the cost and you figure that out well in advance, so you know how and what to do with the equipment on your last day. I have had colleagues who as their last day of work either drove to the office to drop of their equipment in person or packed their stuff and went to the post office to ship it back.

> Also, how are my health insurance and unemployment benefits affected?

Not at all. They paid whatever they have to pay from your salary (unemployment, health insurance, taxes), they just kept the part they owe *you* personally, until their equipment is returned.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150093/discussion-on-answer-by-nvoigt-is-it-normal-legal-in-germany-for-employer-to-wit); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: note this should not be taken out of context, and should have more caveats: This is not legal advice and shouldn't be taken as such. I'm not personally convinced this would hold up as such in court, but I don't know any better. Realistically, it's the best approach to take anyway: give back the equipment, get the salary.

Comment: It is often the case that statutory law overrides contractural obligations. In Australia, the employer would not be able to withhold wages, regardless of whatever agreement was in place.

Comment: They can't withhold the full salary (see https://www.hensche.de/Rechtsanwalt_Arbeitsrecht_Handbuch_Zurueckbehaltungsrecht.html#), they cannot take the "unpfändbarer Teil". If they did that part wrong, it's possible they also messed up the social security payments, which would be a problem for the employer as that is illegal. If the employer kept the full salary the asker has a claim here, they were not allowed to do that